# Show that Hausdorff measure is semifinite

Tags: fractals

I am currently reading a book about fractals and the author states the result that Hausdorff measure is semifinite. Can someone tell me how to prove or provide a hint for me?

Comment: What does "semifinite" mean?

Comment: For every measurable set A which has infinite measure,there exists a subset B of A,which has positive finite measure.

Comment: This is not easy, and I would not want to reproduce the proof here. See Theorem 8.19 in [Geometry of Sets and Measures in Euclidean Spaces](http://books.google.com/books?id=RTQmlDw9r6gC) by Pertti Mattila.